# is it possible to omit lines from template in the produced document?

Tags: pdftex, minted, shell-escape

My tex files look like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=13.20cm,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{solarized}

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted{php}{create_array.php}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

and `create_array.php` (and all other php files) begin with the line `<?php`.  That line is required for their code to work, and required for the highlighting to work... but I don't want to display that line in the pdfs I'm generating.  Is it possible to omit that line from the document I'm producing?

Comment: see the minted manual page 24 the `firstline=2` key will make it start from line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @David Carlisle... use the Minted's `firstline` option like so:

```
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted[firstline=2]{php}{create_array.php}
\end{LARGE}
```